# What is the difference between section and label in assembly in NASM?

Tags: assembly, label, nasm, sections

I am currently studying assembly through NASM assembler and I get
stuck in the difference between **section** and **label**. I
understood that `section .dat`, `.bss` or `.text` are used as a
standard to declaration or initialization of variables and as a linker hook
such as `main()` in C. But also, **labels** are used to assign a
*section* in the code. So what is the obscure truth behind this?

Comment: A *section* is a region of memory associated with a specific purpose, e.g. `.text`, for executable code, or `.rodata` for read-only data (constants). A *label* is a memory address, specifying a variable in memory, or the beginning of an extended basic block of code.

Comment: So If I got it, section is a pre-defined region of memory associated with a specific purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there's a nice Manual, you know. http://www.nasm.us if you haven't got it.

It matters which output format you're using - the `-f` switch. In general... `section` and `segment` are aliases, they do the same thing. They are not case sensitive, you can use `SEGMENT` if you want to. Most output formats (not `-f obj`) have "known names" - `.text`, `.data`, `.bss` (and a few more). These are case sensitive - `section .TEXT` may not do what you want. Typically, `section .text` is executable, but read-only. Attempting to write to it will cause a segmentation fault (or whatever Windows calls it - GPF?). `section .data` is for your initialized data - `msg db "Hello World!", 0` or `frooble_count dd 42`. `section .bss` is for uninitialized data it only reserves space in memory - and is not included in the disk file. You can only use the "reserve" pseudo-instructions there - `resb`, `resw`, `resd`, etc. The parameter after it indicates how many bytes (etc.) you want to reserve. In `-f bin` output format there are no sections/segments (that's what makes it a "flat binary") - Nasm just makes `.text` first, moves `.data` after it, and `.bss` last - you can write 'em in any order you want.

Labels do NOT define a section! Nasm just translates them to numbers - the address where they occur in your code - and that's what appears in your executable. You can use a label as a variable name, or as a point in your code that you might want to `call` or `jmp` to. All the same to Nasm. Some assemblers "remember" the size you said a variable was, and will throw an error if you try to use it wrong. Nasm has amnesia - you can do `mov [mybyte], eax` without complaint. Sometimes this is useful, more often it's an error. A variable that's "too big" is generally not a problem - a variable that's "too small" can cause an error, which often doesn't show up until later. Tough to debug! A label may not start with a decimal digit (and a number must start with a decimal digit). A label that starts with a period (dot) is a local label. Its scope is from the last non-local label to the next non-local label. See the Friendly Manual for (much) more detail - this is just an intro.

The word "main" doesn't mean anything special to Nasm, but is known to C (if you're linking against C). Some compilers spell it `main`, some `_main`, some (OpenWatcom) even spell it `main_`. It is the entrypoint - where execution starts when control is passed to your program. It does not need to be the first thing in `section .text`  - but should be in that section, and should be declared "global" to tell the linker about it. "_start" is the default entrypoint for Linux (etc.). Unlike "main" it is not `call`ed, so you can't `ret` from it. Another name can be used, but you'll need to tell ld about it (`-e myentry`). It too should be `global`.

That's enough for now. See the Manual, and come back if (Ha!) you have other questions.

Comment: Pretty sure `bss` is not "uninitialized" as such. It's implicitly zero-initialized, because all pages the OS allocates to the program are zeroed to prevent one program from reading another's old data.

Comment: Right. In a DOS .com file - where there aren't really any "sections" - you can set a value in .bss, end the program, and run it again without having loaded anything else, and find your value still there. So in that one case, .bss is truely "uninitialized". DOS isn't too good with "security". In all(?) other cases, .bss is zero-filled by the OS. I'm not sure we're supposed to "count on" that, but it's true. I was trying to keep it simple. Maybe too simple. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: NASM's bin format does support multiple sections with different names, `start=`, `vstart=`, `follows=`, `vfollows=`, `align=` and `valign=` parameters.