# Trivial assembler program segfaults

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm, ld

I feel like asking a very stupid question but was not able to find anything useful so far...

So I have like the most trivial assembler programm imaginable which goes like this

```
SECTION .TEXT
        GLOBAL _start

_start:
        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

I use nasm to generate an object file like

```
nasm -f elf64 -o test.o test.asm
```

Link with ld like

```
ld -o test test.o
```

Running the resulting executable results in a segfault

```
./test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As I have been able to find some assembler examples online that have exactly the same assembler program and which do apparently execute successfully I guess there must be something wrong with either my call to nasm or to ld. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Results of readelf do not look suspicious to me but I'm not too familiar with that

```
readelf -a test
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x401000
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4352 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         5
  Section header string table index: 4

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .TEXT             PROGBITS         0000000000401000  00001000
       000000000000000c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00001010
       00000000000000a8  0000000000000018           3     3     8
  [ 3] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  000010b8
       0000000000000022  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [ 4] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000010da
       0000000000000021  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), l (large), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x000000000000100c 0x000000000000100c  R      0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .TEXT

There is no dynamic section in this file.

There are no relocations in this file.
No processor specific unwind information to decode

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 7 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test.asm
     2: 000000000040100c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _end
     3: 0000000000401000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _start
     4: 000000000040200c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __bss_start
     5: 000000000040200c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _edata
     6: 0000000000402010     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _end

No version information found in this file.
```

Same goes for objdump

```
objdump -D test.o

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .TEXT:

0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
   5:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
   a:   0f 05                   syscall
```

Comment: `.text` is a special section name, `.TEXT` isn't, so `nasm` and `ld` put your code in a program segment with read but not exec permission (as you can see from readelf, and the fact that you had to use `objdump -D` not `-d`).  [What is the difference between section and label in assembly in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27073501) mentions this, but isn't a duplicate; I'm pretty sure we've had SO questions about this before, but it's hard to find them with SO or google searches which seem to be case insensitive.

Comment: @PeterCordes, you're right. That solved the issue. How embarassing... Thank you so much! :-)